# Simple decoding program C++

Tags: c++, decoding

I am doing a C++ course and middle way through the scholastic year we get a mock cw/exercise to do. it is not marked, it is only for practice.
basically, we have to do this

> (a)Read text from a file and store its content in any array of
>   characters A. (b)Calculate the number and percentage of occurrences of
>   each letter in A using two parallel arrays (B and C): one containing
>   26 alphabet letters and the other containing their corresponding
>   percentage of occurrence. (c)Use a sorting algorithm (for example,
>   bubble sort algorithm) to sort the above two parallel arrays in
>   descending order of the percentage of occurrence. (d)Apply (b) and (c)
>   to the training and the encoded texts. Store both sets of parallel
>   arrays (for the training and the encoded texts) for further use.
>   (e)Use the above two sets of sorted parallel arrays to find and
>   display a one-to-one mapping of letters in the training and encoded
>   texts. (f)Substitutes the letters in the encoded message for letters
>   they represent (g)Ask interactively the user for a pair of characters,
>   store them in two character variables (for example, X and Y) and
>   substitute all occurrences of letter X for letter Y in an array of
>   characters. (h)Save the decoded text stored in an array of characters
>   to a file. (i)Be able to repeat (f), (g) and (h) as many times as the
>   user wishes.

We gotta do a procedural code first, then object oriented.

```
    #include <fstream> //for file I/O
#include <iostream> //for cout, endl
#include <string> //for countletters
using namespace std;

int countletters(/*in*/ int& sum) //counting the number of letters contained in the file
{
    string line;
    ifstream inData ;
    inData.open("encoded.txt");
    while(!inData.eof())
    {
        getline(inData,line);
        int numofChars= line.length();
        for (unsigned int n = 0; n<line.length();n++)
        { 
            if (line.at(n) == ' ')
            {
            numofChars--;
            }
        }
        sum=numofChars+sum;
    }
    inData.close();
    //sum is the number of letters inside the encoded.txt file
}

void fileintoarray(int& sum)
{
  int arraysize = sum;
  char myArray[arraysize];
  char current_char;
  int num_characters = 0;
  int i = 0;

  ifstream myfile ("encoded.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while (!myfile.eof())
            {
                myfile >> myArray[i];
                i++;
                num_characters ++;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= num_characters; i++)
            {
                cout << myArray[i];
            }
            system("pause");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int sum=0;
    countletters();
    fileintoarray();
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I wrote so far, and the second function doesn't work. 
It fails to compile.

Can anyone please help me on this one?

Comment: _'doesn't work'_ is pretty vague!

Comment: what doesn't work , does it not compile ?

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing the variable "sum" in your function "fileintoarray", but it's not in scope there as you declared it in "countletters".

Learn how to return values and how to pass parameters to functions - or, if you haven't learned that yet and are supposed to get along anyways - use global variables, because that's a little like the object-oriented version will be.

Comment: In class the lecturer told us that global variables are a big no-no.
I'm trying to use pass-by-reference indeed. is this the change I should make "int countletters(int& sum)"?

also if I substitute sum for an integer, the compiler will fail.

Comment: In that case, you will have to let the first function return the sum. You can then store it into a variable in main and pass it to the other function from there.

Comment: updated question above.

Comment: I updated the original code with what I believe is the correct sintax. Yet the compile still fails..

Comment: Your function lacks a return statement to actually return the integer, i.e. "return sum" at the end of the function. Then you have to actually assign the return value in main: int sum = countletters(). Finally, you need to pass that value to fileintoarray, i.e. fileintoarray(sum)